# AttributeError at /blog/tag/security/. 'TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'get_reverse_joining_fields'

Tags: python, django

when i try to navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/tag/security/ i get error saying *'TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'get_reverse_joining_fields'*.

when run the code this way *http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/* i get correct output
I have read django documentation it suggests doing it in the same way but I have no idea what went wrong. I would really appreciate any help.

*models.py *

````
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank = True, max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="author_post")```

*admin.py*

from .models import Comment, Post

# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','slug','body', 'slug','author', 'created', 'publish','updated','status')
    search_fields = ('author__username','title')
    list_filter = ('title','author__username','created')
    search_help_text="Search by author username or title"
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ['author'] 

*views.py*

def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(status=Post.Status.PUBLISH)
    tag = None
    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug = tag_slug)
        post_list = post_list.filter(tags__name__in=[tag])
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 100)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page',1)
    try:
        posts=paginator.page(page_number)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts=paginator.page(paginator.num_pages) 
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', context={"posts":posts, 'tag':tag})

*urls.py* --> app level

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='blog'

urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('<int:id>/share/', views.post_share, name='post_share'),
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
    path('<int:id>/comment/', views.post_comment, name='post_comment'),
    path('post/<int:id>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
````